# Wait till we are able to click the element in selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

If I want to wait until element is not available to click, we code:-

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='my-button my-button--size_large my-button--primary my-button--loader' and @type='submit']")))
```

What can I do if I want to wait until element is available to click. In other words, wait till the submit button is available & execute other code when submit button is **not** available?

Comment: You want to do some other work in that website until that submit button is available, right?

Comment: @Xitiz no after that submit button is gone / vanished

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find_elements` like this :

```
try:
    if len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "xpath of submit button")) > 0:
        print("this means submit button is available")
        # do whatever you wanna do here
    else:
        print("You are seeing this cause submit button is not available in DOM")
        # do whatever you wanna do here when submit button is not available
except:
    print("something went wrong")
    pass
```

Comment: will be still looking for answers, as using if else, i have to shift my working code to fit it in if else. There were some changes in the site which now I have to add this extra.

Comment: I can also skip the else part here if we do: `if len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "xpath of submit button")) < 0:`

Comment: that will only be applicable if you wanna do something when button is available, but in that case you won't have a way to handle "when button is not available"

Comment: i used `<` instead of *>*

Comment: I know, why do you not wanna use else  ? I don't understand that, it would give you more control on the flow.

Comment: Yeah, that will have more option but also, its not fix when it will be removed so, we need `WebDriverWait` to be used.